# quartz: documentation for xml files?

Tags: java, xml, quartz-scheduler

Where is the documentation for quartz xml files (specifically jobs.xml)? I found the [javadoc](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/docs/api/index.html) online, but I can't seem to find the documentation for how to write an xml file, just some brief examples e.g. [this one from O'Reilly](http://onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/2005/09/28/what-is-quartz.html?page=4).

**edit:** apparently the java class that reads the jobs.xml is [JobInitializationPlugin](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/docs/api/index.html), but I don't see the docs for the xml format there either.

Answer (score 5):

This is really poorly documented.  Beyond the [brief mention at the OpenSymphony site](http://www.opensymphony.com/quartz/wikidocs/JobInitPlugin.html), the only documentation comes in the form of a [Document Type Definition (DTD)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Type_Definition) and an [XML Schema](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_Schema_%28W3C%29).  If you're familiar with these formats, you can use them to figure out what tags are available.

If you download the [full Quartz distribution](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/download/index.html), they are located at `/quartz/src/main/resources/org/quartz/xml/`.  You can also find them inside of quartz-1.7.3.jar at `/org/quartz/xml/`.  The files are named `job_scheduling_data_1_5.dtd` and `job_scheduling_data_1_5.xsd`.

Comment: thanks. this is really surprising; I thought Quartz is widely used.