# Recursive function call with time delay

Tags: java, multithreading, web-services, recursion, scheduled-tasks

I have a web application, I need to run a backgroung process which will hit a web-service, after getting the response it will wait for few seconds(say 30) then again hit the service. The response data can vary from very less to very large, so i dont want to call the processagain untill i am finished with processing of data. So, its a recursive call with a time delay. How i intend to do is:

1. Add a ContextListener to web app.
2. On contextIntialized() method , call invokeWebService() i.e. arbitary method to hit web service.
3. invokeWebService will look like:

   ```
   invokeWebService()
   {

   //make request

   //hit service

   //get response

   //process response

   timeDelayInSeconds(30);

   //recursive call
   invokeWebService();

   }
   ```

Pls. suggest whether I am doing it right. Or go with threads or schedulers. Pls. answer with sample codes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a [`ScheduledExecutorService`, which is part of the standard JDK since 1.5](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html):

```
    ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
    Runnable r = new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            invokeWebService();
        }
    };

    scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(r, 0, 30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Comment: Well, yes, if you know that invoceWebService() won't spend more time than 30 seconds. If not, it's not a good solution.

Answer (score 1):

It is not recursive but repeated. You have two choice here:

- Use a Timer and a TimerTask with scheduleAtFixedRate
- Use Quartz with a repeated schedule.

In quartz, you can create a repeated schedule with this code:

```
TriggerBuilder.newTrigger().withSchedule(SimpleScheduleBuilder.repeatSecondlyForever(30))
                .build()
```

Comment: Its not repeated, since i dont want to move forward until i processes response of web service.

Comment: Yes it is repeated. The way you are doing it now will at some point reach a stackOverFlow because you are invoking your code recursively but you are never exiting the recursion. Go go the repeated way to do exactly what you want

Comment: WHat exactly repeatSecondlyForever() do.

Comment: Quartz is a job scheduling framework. For each Job you define two things: the Job and the Trigger (when it will be performed, repeatedly or not, etc...). The line above will simply create a trigger that will repeat the Job over and over every 30 seconds (until you stop the application)

Comment: `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor` should be favoured over `Timer` when using Java 1.5+.

Answer (score 1):

From what I am getting, waiting sort of implies hanging, which I do not really think is a good idea. I would recommend you use something such as [Quartz](http://quartz-scheduler.org/) and run your method at whatever interval you wish.

> Quartz is a full-featured, open source job scheduling service that can
>   be integrated with, or used along side virtually any Java EE or Java
>   SE application

Tutorials can be accessed [here](http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/tutorials/).

As stated in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2676295/quartz-preventing-concurrent-instances-of-a-job-in-jobs-xml) you can do something like so:

```
JobDetail existingJobDetail = sched.getJobDetail(jobName, jobGroup);
    if (existingJobDetail != null) {
        List<JobExecutionContext> currentlyExecutingJobs = (List<JobExecutionContext>) sched.getCurrentlyExecutingJobs();
        for (JobExecutionContext jec : currentlyExecutingJobs) {
            if(existingJobDetail.equals(jec.getJobDetail())) {
                //String message = jobName + " is already running.";
                //log.info(message);
                //throw new JobExecutionException(message,false);
            }
        }
        //sched.deleteJob(jobName, jobGroup); if you want to delete the scheduled but not-currently-running job
    }
```

Comment: I tried with scheduler, problem is say process time varies from 2 to 30 minutes depending upon response data. If i take trigger time as 30 minutes, it will be too much for process and if i take 2, next process runs before fisrt has been completed.

Comment: @shashankaholic: Quartz seems to provide some mechanism to do what you need.

Comment: Thanks.Can you tell me if annotation @DisallowConcurrentExecution  over JOb class will help me here. If not, where exactly i need to implement the code you citated.

Comment: According to this: http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/examples/Example4 you need to put it at the very beginning of your class decleration.