# Regarding stopwatch or timer or some other utility

Tags: java

I have a requirement to start a task..Now many threads can start this task and this task normally takes 4-5 seconds to complete. I want to prevent the starting of a task if this task has been already started by some other thread.
In order to implement this requirement, I am thinking of starting a timer or stopwatch in a different thread whenever the task is started by some thread. Now when the timer times out after a configured time-interval, another thread can starts a task.
So, is starting a timer or stopwatch in a different thread to see if the particular time has been reached is a good solution?Is there any good alternative for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to do this in java then you can consider using a synchronized block on the Object Oriented approach on JAVA.

So any task that you want to make sure is done by one thread at a time then make a class and a synchronized method in that class, also make sure you all the threads share the same object of the class and call this method in which they want to perform the task.

For Example

```
Class SyncTask{


synchronized void task1(){

//Perform your task here


}

}
```

Create the object of this class once during the lifetime of your application and then use this same object across all the threads and let them call this method to which you want to perform your task.

In the case of multiple threads invoking this method at the same time. JVM will take care of the sequence and if one thread is already performing a task, the others calling it will wait for the first one to finish.

In this way you will be sure that only on thread is performing the task at any given time.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, this is a bad idea. Basically you are assumming your job will never run for more than 5 seconds so if the watch tells you that some job was started less than 5 seconds ago, you won't start another one. This is very unreliable.

Instead create some sort of flag that you set when job starts and unset when ends. `AtomicBoolean` is perfect for that:

```
private AtomicBoolean flag = new AtomicBoolean();

//...

if(!flag.getAndSet(true)) {
    try {
        //do your work
    } finally {
        flag.set(false);
    }
} else {
    //Already running
}
```

If you want another job to wait for the previous one instead of simply being discarded, just surround your task with `synchronized` or use some different locking mechanism.

Note: if your jobs are distributed you will need a distributed locking mechanism, like a databasse or [hazelcast](/questions/tagged/hazelcast).

Comment: My task is to ping a device and the task thread will time-out in 5 seconds if the device is not pinging..Now I don't want to choke the network to send the call again to see if the device is not pinging.Instead, I want to send a call after a particular time for this device to see if the device is online again or not.

Comment: @ashishgupta_mca: so if two threads are trying to ping the device within 1 second, what should happen with second request? Should it be discarded, should it wait until the first one finishes, should it wait at least 5 second after the first one started (to keep max 1 request per 5 seconds throughput)? Depending on your requirements we can suggest very different optimal solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to schedule task the framework of choice is usually something similar to [Quartz](http://quartz-scheduler.org/). It should allow you to do what you need and more. Regarding the issue of non running concurrent tasks, I would recommend you take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2676295/quartz-preventing-concurrent-instances-of-a-job-in-jobs-xml) previous SO post which should point you in the right direction.